# Filtering a list in Java while avoiding ConcurrentModificationException in o(n) complexity

Tags: java, iterator, time-complexity, concurrentmodification

I found out that apparently iterator.remove() has an o(n) complexity. Anybody, knows of a way of filtering a list while avoiding ConcurrentModificationException without using iterator.remove().

Following is a code snippet showing the difference. It creates a large array list and then deletes large part of it from the middle using it.remove().
Then it does the same thing just this time from the start. On my machine it reads:
First test 699962ms
Second test 329181ms

clearly a big difference

```
package src;

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        long before, after;

        double elements = Math.pow(10, 3);

        for(int i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
            a.add(i);
        }

        Iterator<Integer> it = a.iterator();
        for(int i = 0; i < elements * 0.4; i++){
            it.next();
        }

        before = System.nanoTime();
        for(int i = 0; i < elements * 0.5; i++){
            it.remove();
            it.next();
        }
        after = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(after - before);

        a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
            a.add(i);
        }


        before = System.nanoTime();
        it = a.iterator();
        it.next();
        for(int i = 0; i < elements * 0.5; i++){
            it.remove();
            it.next();
        }
        after = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(after - before);


    }
}
```

Comment: Try it with a `LinkedList`. Also your test is nowhere near a proper benchmark, so any times or performance comparisons you think you're getting out of this are wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: The time complexity has nothing to do with the iterator and everything to do with the type of list you're using.

Comment: Besides, you should just use `List.removeIf()`.

Comment: Maybe it's not a proper bunchmark but the iterator.remove() still has o(n) complexity. After testing with LinkedList I got these results:
412330
88829

Seems like the problem still holds.

Comment: You can get all sorts of results from broken benchmarks. However, you don't need to worry about that when taking my advice.

Answer (score 1):

As informed, your benchmark is incorrect. Considering that a single remove from an `ArrayList` made with either `remove()` or `Iterator.remove()` is an `O(n)` operation (unless removing the last element) due to the resizing of the internal array, the code won't perform well under any circumstances.

A `LinkedList` would provide you an `O(1)` removal while iterating it, but you should go for the easiest solution and use `List.removeIf()`. `ArrayList` overrides it for `O(n)` performance and avoids `CME` too.